# Programatically change icon resource on click

Tags: android, android-intent, icons, shortcut

I am trying to change the source of the Intent.EXTRA_SHORTCUT_ICON_RESOURCE

```
public class ShortcutActivity extends Activity {
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    // The meat of our shortcut
    final Intent shortcutIntent = new Intent(this, ShortcutResult.class);
    ShortcutIconResource iconResource = Intent.ShortcutIconResource
            .fromContext(this, R.drawable.test);
    // The result we are passing back from this activity
    Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SHORTCUT_INTENT, shortcutIntent);
    intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SHORTCUT_NAME, "Shortcut Test");
    intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SHORTCUT_ICON_RESOURCE, iconResource);

    setResult(RESULT_OK, intent);

    finish(); // Must call finish for result to be returned immediately
}
```

I access another activity that starts a service. When the service starts and stops, I want to be able to alternate between the two images.

```
    @Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    sharedPrefs = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("eePrefs2",
            Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    editor = sharedPrefs.edit();

    if (sharedPrefs.getBoolean("service_running", false) == false) {
        startService(new Intent(this, service.class));
        editor.putBoolean("service_running", true);
        ShortcutIconResource iconResource = Intent.ShortcutIconResource
                .fromContext(this, R.drawable.test);
    } else if (sharedPrefs.getBoolean("service_running", false) == true) {
        stopService(new Intent(this, service.class));
        editor.putBoolean("service_running", false);
        ShortcutIconResource iconResource = Intent.ShortcutIconResource
                .fromContext(this, R.drawable.test2);
    }
    Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SHORTCUT_ICON_RESOURCE, iconResource);
    setResult(RESULT_OK, intent);
    editor.commit();
    finish();

}
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

That is not possible. There is no protocol to tell an arbitrary home screen to change your shortcut icon.

Instead, you can create an app widget, which gives you much more control over the presentation.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think the [ShortcutIconResource](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.ShortcutIconResource.html) is what you are looking for. Are you trying to change an icon in the ActionBar while a service is running? Or are you trying to change the icon for the entire application while a service is running?